# Different Commits - Error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge

Tags: git, gitignore

I am trying to set up production, testing and development environments for a site. It came to the time of pushing the first minor change to production. However, when I try to do it, it gives the following error:

> error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten
>   by merge:
>
> CHANGELOG.txt
>    COPYRIGHT.txt
>    Blockquote
>           INSTALL.mysql.txt
>           INSTALL.pgsql.txt
>           INSTALL.sqlite.txt
>           INSTALL.txt
>           LICENSE.txt
>           MAINTAINERS.txt
>           README.txt
>           UPGRADE.txt
>           misc/arrow-asc.png
>           misc/arrow-desc.png
>           misc/configure.png
>           misc/draggable.png

The list of files goes on and I omitted them for brevity.

My production and development .gitignore are identical. Namely, they are as follows:

```
# Ignore configuration files that may contain sensitive information.
sites/*/settings*.php
.htaccess

# Ignore paths that contain user-generated content.
sites/*/files
sites/*/private
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======

# Compiled source #
###################
*.com
*.class
*.dll
*.exe
*.o
*.so

# Packages #
############
# it's better to unpack these files and commit the raw source
# git has its own built in compression methods
*.7z
*.dmg
*.gz
*.iso
*.jar
*.rar
*.tar
*.zip

# Images #
############
*.jpg
*.gif
*.png
*.pdf
*.tiff

# Logs and databases #
######################
*.log
*.sql
*.sqlite

# OS generated files #
######################
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db


# Ignore default text files
robots.txt
/CHANGELOG.txt
/COPYRIGHT.txt
/INSTALL*.txt
/LICENSE.txt
/MAINTAINERS.txt
/UPGRADE.txt
/README.txt
sites/README.txt
sites/all/modules/README.txt
sites/all/themes/README.txt
>>>>>>> 07326d6660b93c61b407c37a1582a37d5c374905
```

What can I do to fix this? I assume this issue has to do with how Git ignores files.

Comment: It looks as if you are in the process of a merge conflict, or are the >>>>>>> and <<<<<<< intentional?

Comment: No, not intentional. I assume you are right.

Comment: A conflict is easy to solve, but I'm afraid your workflow may have some problem since the files are untracked. I wonder which git command led to this conflict in your case.

Comment: I was trying to do a git pull from BitBucket repository.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore those files (like README.txt), and yet those same files are part of an error message like `The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:`, that means they are still tracked.

As long as they are tracked, the .gitignore won't apply.

```
git rm --cached README.txt
git commit -m "remove README.txt"
```

If you do that on both branches, you can then merge one into another without having that can of error message.